# Split string logic in J2ME

Tags: java-me

I am developing a J2ME application.

I want to split the following string at `"<br>"` & comma:

```
3,toothpaste,2<br>4,toothbrush,3
```

How can I do this?

Comment: sorry but there is a br tag in between those two records

Comment: I fixed the formatting so the <br> is obvious.

Comment: You can Simply use `StringTokenizer` Class

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
  private String[] split(String original,String separator) {
    Vector nodes = new Vector();
    // Parse nodes into vector
    int index = original.indexOf(separator);
    while(index >= 0) {
        nodes.addElement( original.substring(0, index) );
        original = original.substring(index+separator.length());
        index = original.indexOf(separator);
    }
    // Get the last node
    nodes.addElement( original );

     // Create split string array
    String[] result = new String[ nodes.size() ];
    if( nodes.size() > 0 ) {
        for(int loop = 0; loop < nodes.size(); loop++)
        {
            result[loop] = (String)nodes.elementAt(loop);
            System.out.println(result[loop]);
        }

    }
   return result;
}
```

The above method will let you split a string about the passed separator, much like J2EE's String.split(). So first split the string on the line break tag, and then do it at each offset of the returned array for the "," comma.
e.g.

```
 String[] lines = this.split(myString,"<br>");
 for(int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) 
 {
      String[] splitStr = this.split(lines[i],",");
      System.out.println(splitStr[0] + " " + splitStr[1] + " " + splitStr[2]);     
 }
```

Comment: Should read :
    `// Get the last node
    if (!"".equals(original_element)) {
     nodes.addElement(original_element);
    }`

Comment: Why did you revert my edit ? There is a bug - I run into it using your code - if the string has the form `<string><separator>` the result will be `[<string>, ""]` - Please correct !

Answer (score 1):

```
private String[] split(String original, String separator, int count)
{
    String[] result;
    int index = original.indexOf(separator);
    if(index >= 0)
        result = split(original.substring(index + separator.length()), separator, count + 1);
    else
    {
        result = new String[count + 1];
        index = original.length();
    }
    result[count] = original.substring(0, index);
    return result;
}

String[] lines = this.split(myString,"<br>",0);
```