# How can I make my midlet send an SMS message to multiple recipients

Tags: java, java-me, sms, midp, wma

I am currently working on a midlet for sending SMS messages. I made use of a textfield and specified the Input constraints as phone numbers (this constraints allow for automatic search for numbers in a phone for a Nokia platform). But the disadvantage is that it only accepts *(asterics) and # as the delimiters. It doesn't allow for ;(semicolon) to be used.
Please I need an algorithm that allows for an SMS to be sent to multiple recipients.

Comment: we....need.....codes....to..help..you......

Answer (score 1):

You can send multiple SMS using the loop or any iteration concept. For example suppose if you are adding `;` end of the number means you can [split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657627/split-string-logic-in-j2me) that number using `;` separator and add that number's into `Vector` and the use the loop for sending SMS.